# Combining separate CHColorStructureDiagrams to form one molecular structure

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

I am trying to attach a fructose molecule to a sucrose molecule by using information obtained from the following

```
ChemicalData["Sucrose", "CHColorStructureDiagram"]
ChemicalData["Fructose", "CHColorStructureDiagram"]
```

My question is how do you combine each separate structure diagram to form a single one shown here which is a combined structure arising from the two structures (description at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fructan)
[image]

Comment: I would suggest to use ChemDraw or some other dedicated software for this kind of work. It will most likely save a lot of time and look better.

Comment: @paw The advantage with MMA ver10 is that once some module is set up properly, the generation of structures with any no. of units can be programmed easily....it may save time in the long run....especially when you are looking at generating long structures.